# Nsight installation on both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, installation, nsight

I am using Windows 7 64bit on a Notebook with a GeForce GT 650M, driver version 335.23.
I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional + SP1 and Visual Studio 2012 Professional installed.

I need to use the CUDA Toolkit 5.5 on both of them, but when I launch the installer of Nsight Visual Studio Edition 3.2.2., it is installed only on VS2012 and not on VS2010. It says:

```
Installed:
 - Nsight for Visual Studio 2012
 - Nsight Monitor and HUD Launcher
 - Nsight C++ AMP Debugger for Visual Studio 2012
 - Nsight C++ AMP Target Support for MSVSMON
Not Installed:
 - Nsight for Visual Studio 2010
   Reason: VS2010 was not found
 - Nsight for Visual Studio 2008
   Reason: VS2008 SP1 was not found
```

My questions are: it is possible to install Nsight on multiple versions of Visual Studio? And if it is, how can I do this?

Thank you for your support.

Best,
Giulia

Answer (score 0):

Nsight supports multiple versions of VS for sure as long as VS is installed correctly.

Could you make sure your VS2010 is workable? One thing is check regkey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ApplicationID. It should be "VisualStudio". If there is, would you mind paste your VS2010's version? Thanks.

Comment: I have checked and indeed I have this key set to "VisualStudio" both for the 10.0 and the 11.0 versions... My VS2010 version is: 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel.

Comment: There should a "InstallDir" key in the key Qian provided as well, which has the path to the Visual Studio installation (most likely C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\)
From the above path, we check that devenv.com exists.  If that still seems ok, please run msiexec /i "<Nsight_installer_name>.msi" /l*v "installer.log" and send us the installer.log file to devtools-support at nvidia dot com   thanks!